# Bash substitution with variable defined from a glob pattern

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, quoting, wildcards

The below example explains the issue. Why is the `FILENAME` printed correctly when echoed and perceived as a pattern when using substitution?

```
#!/bin/bash

FILEPATH_WITH_GLOB="/home/user/file_*"
FILENAME=$(basename "$FILEPATH_WITH_GLOB")
echo $FILENAME                #file_1234
echo ${FILENAME:1:5}          #ile_*   <---why is this not ile_1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> ```
> FILEPATH_WITH_GLOB="/home/user/file_*"
> ```

Now, `FILEPATH_WITH_GLOB` contains `/home/user/file_*`

> ```
> FILENAME=$(basename "$FILEPATH_WITH_GLOB")
> ```

`FILENAME` contains `file_*`.

> ```
> echo $FILENAME                #file_1234
> ```

`$FILENAME` being unquoted in list context, that expansion undergoes the split+glob operator, so that's expanded to the list of matching file: *filename generation* is performed upon *parameter expansion*.

> ```
> echo ${FILENAME:1:5}          #ile_*   <---why is this not ile_1
> ```

It's still an unquoted parameter expansion in list context, so still undergoes split+glob. However here, the `ile_*` pattern doesn't match any file, so it expands to itself instead.

What you probably want here is:

```
shopt -s nullglob # have globs expand to nothing when they don't match
set -- /home/user/file_* # expand that pattern into the list of matching 
                         # files in $1, $2...
for file do  # loop over them
  filename=$(basename -- "$file")
  printf '%s\n' "$filename" "${filename:1:5}"
done
```

Or you can store them in an array:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(/home/user/file_*)
```

If you only care about the first match, or you know there's only one match, you can then refer to that file as `$files`. `bash` has that usually annoying behaviour that `$files` expands to `${files[0]}` instead of all the elements of the array (a behaviour inherited from `ksh`, fixed in `zsh`), but here, that would be a wanted behaviour for once.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Managed to do a workaround with ``FILEPATH_WITH_GLOB=`echo /home/user/file_*` `` after your explanation.

Comment: @Alan, that's the wrong way to address it. You want to use a array here. Either the positional parameters as in my example ($1, $2...) or a `bash` array like: `files=(/home/user/file_*)`.

Comment: (and all upper-case variables should really be reserved for environment variables, [`echo` should not be used for arbitrary data](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803), variables should not be left unquoted in list contexts).