# echo wildcard globing

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, echo

I'm trying to echo a combination of text and variables containing wildcards that I need "unpacked", but I encountered the following behavior:

If I say:

```
FILENAME=somefile*.txt
echo "something:" $FILENAME
```

I get:

```
something: somefile003.txt
```

Which is what I want, but if I say:
If I say:

```
FILENAME=somefile*.txt
echo "something:"$FILENAME
```

I get:

```
something:somefile*.txt
```

So it seems like if there is no space between quotes and the variable it doesn't glob the wildcard. Is there a way to get it to process the * without adding a space?

Comment: It does try to parse the wildcard; there are just no files that match the glob `something:somefile*.txt`.

Comment: If you say `FILENAME = somefile*.txt` your shell will try to execute a program called `FILENAME`. If you say `FILENAME=somefile*.txt` your shell will set a variable called `FILENAME`. Please be precise; it's important.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I see you've edited the question but how do you know which places really contain a space and which don't, given the question is about the effects seen when there is one or not?

Comment: The 'what I get' part of the question would be factually incorrect if there had been spaces as `FILENAME` would not have been assigned to something which could have globbed.

Comment: Perhaps printf would help: `printf "something:%s\n" $FILENAME`.

Comment: Related - [Bash substitution with variable defined from a glob pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210280/bash-substitution-with-variable-defined-from-a-glob-pattern)

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thanks for the edit, that is what I actually meant, I just typed it in incorrectly when writing the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with a shell that handles arrays such as `bash` you can glob into an array, thus

```
FILENAMES=(somefile*.txt)
```

and reference the first element like this

```
echo "something:${FILENAMES[0]}"
```

or all of them like this

```
echo "somethings:${FILENAMES[@]}"
```

I would strongly recommend that you "double quote" your variables when you use them. This avoids them being expanded into multiple words unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define your variable like this:

```
FILENAME=\ somefile*.txt; # that is, with a leading space ... and then
echo "something:"$FILENAME;
```

this gets variable interpolated to...     something: somefile*.txt

then this gets wildcard expanded to... something: somefile003.txt

these two arguments then get passed to echo which promptly takes them stdout.